# How to use the correspondence theorem to calculate the ideals of the ring $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{12Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to use the correspondence theorem to calculate the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{12Z}$?

Let $A$ be a ring and let $I$ be an ideal of $A$. Then there exists a bijection between the set of ideals of $A$ containing $I$ and the set of ideals of $A / I$ .
$i.e$ :
There exists a bijection $\lambda : \{ J \,/\, J\,$ ideal $\,of\,A\,; I \subset J \} \to \{K\, / \,K\,$ ideal $\, of\,A/I \}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}$$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$Go through these steps.

1. What are the ideals of $\Z$?

Answer:

> An ideal of $\Z$ can be written uniquely in the form $n \Z$, for $n \in \N$ (natural numbers including $0$).

2. When is it the case that one ideal contains the other?

Answer:

> $n \Z \supseteq m \Z$ if and only if $n \mid m$.

3. Which ideals of $\Z$ contain $12 \Z$?

Answer:

> The ideals $n \Z$, for $n \in \N$ such that $n \mid 12$, so that $n = \dots$.

4. What are the ideals of $\Z / 12 \Z$?

Answer

> The ideals of $\Z / 12 \Z$ are of the form $n \Z / 12 \Z$, where $n \in \N$ is such that $n \mid 12$.

Comment: Sir, I need you as my abstract algebra professor! Finally I get it! Thank you so much.

Comment: @JoséMarín, thanks a bunch, but I'm already taken, by my students, that is ;-)